# How do you set the DPI with CFdocument?

Tags: coldfusion, cfdocument

I see parameters on CFdocument like height, width, and unit, but NO DPI.  How do you set DPI?

Comment: Perhaps the person who downvoted could explain why.

Answer (score 2):

I dont think its possible.

A PDF is postscript so any text will scale nicely and if your image quality is bad for print, just embed a higher resolution image.

This has worked for me previously.